# Eclipse Android layout editor - rendering target selector missing

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout

If I remember correctly the Android layout editor had a rendering target selector (a little android figure). However in my editor its not there. I restarded eclipse multiple times but its still missing:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the rendering target is not the same defined in your project build path.

> Right click on your Project -> Properties -> Android -> Select the correct Build Target

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this error now and all I did was clean and rebuild the project (Project -> Clean) and it seems resolved. Also, right click on your project and make sure the "Java Path" under the "Order and Export" tab in Preferences is set to your version of Android.